# Advice on User Authentication

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gitlab, nexus, freeipa

We're looking for a simple open source software, that is easily containerised, that we can use as a single sign on machine inside our cloud development environment.

The servers that it will need to handle authentication for are

gitlab nexus jenkins sonarqube

So far I've looked at freeIPa

https://github.com/freeipa/freeipa-container

Having a few teething troubles getting this setup, and was hoping to get some other suggestions.

To be honest I'm not even certain freeIPA will work with all those software titles anyway, something I'll check now.

Any tips or advice more than welcome.

Here's a basic diagram of what we're trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: Start reading the SonarQube [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authentication)?

Comment: Thanks for responding @JeroenHeier I've checked the docs of all 4 authentication targets, so to speak, and they all support ldap so I'm going to look at something that will handle ldap first of all.